# UIView parent reference

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

If I know a `UIView` has been added to a *parent*, is there a native way to access the *parent* from within the *child*?

eg.
`[self parent] // returns parent UIView`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sure: `UIView` has the `superview` property.

Answer (score 11):

You could try [UIViews property superview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/superview)

```
[self superview]
```

Answer (score -1):

in the Childs .h create a property for the parent:

```
ParentView *parentView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) ParentView *parentView;
```

(make sure to @synthesize your property in Childs .m)

then, when you alloc an instance of child imediatly asign self to the parentView property

in Parent .m:

```
Child *child = [[Child alloc] init];
[child setParentView:self];
```

then you can access the Parent view from the Child with:

```
[self parentView];
```

Comment: This is not a *native* way of doing this as the OP asked for. The `superview` property in `UIView` serves as a native way to accomplish this. Another note: Nowadays it's not necessary to synthesize properties anymore. :-}